# Clicking on markers at google map shows the same text for all

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I connect to the the database and get some information as a json then I Show them when I do this it can easily recognize lan and longtitude and show them on map but when it comes to text that I return to show it when user click on the markers just one text is shown for all and it seems that it attaches the text to first marker for all other markers attach the same text what am I missing? I am totally confused!

```
for (var i=0; i<tweetsToPlot.length; i++){
        var lat = tweetsToPlot[i].lat;
        var lng = tweetsToPlot[i].lng;
        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        var txt=tweetsToPlot[i].text;
         var myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: myLatLng,
              title: "LatLng Feb 17",
              map:map
             }); 

        google.maps.event.addListener(myMarker, 'click', function() {
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
              content: txt
            });
            infowindow.open(map, this);
          });

        var index = tweetsToPlot[i].id;
        discs[index] = myMarker;
       myMarker.setVisible(true);   
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps JS API v3 - Simple Multiple Marker Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example)

Answer (score 0):

You need closures. Your `myMarker` variable keeps changing, so even though you've assigned the click handler to the marker, the actual *reference* to the marker keeps changing as you iterate through your loop.

... at least, that's what it sounds like (and the symptoms match).

```
(function(markerObj) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(myMarker, 'click', function() {
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: txt
        });
        infowindow.open(map, this);
    });
})(myMarker);
```

Comment: Thanks  I did that but still I have the same problem

Comment: Also my markers are shown correctly but thier text does not update